# The project is not built when adding Yandex maps (mapkit)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, yandex-mapkit

I want to add Yandex maps and add a dependency to Gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.4.0'  
}
```

When building a solution, Gradle swears. What might be the problem

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find core.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.1.0/core-1.1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to sanctions, as soon as the proxy is connected, the Internet connection is restored and the packets are downloaded